# Multiple header files in one class C++ (Arduino)

Tags: c++

I have an class that includes methods from different header files like this:

```
#include "ICash.h"
#include "ILock.h"

class control: public ICash, public ILock
{
  public:
      control();

  private:
     void doSomething(int value);

};
```

So now when i make an instance of ICash through control class. 
where in control.cpp the methodes are declared.

Is is possible to use the method doSomething from control throug the ICash interface?

thanks.

Comment: Make doSomething virtual in ICash.

Answer (score 2):

In `control.cpp`, for example, you can have this implementation code:

```
control::control() { /* ctor body */ }

void control::doSomething(int value)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Then, somewhere, you can use a `control` instance via a pointer to `ICash`

```
ICash *cash = new control;
```

If `doSomething` was not `private`, you could use `void doSomething(int)` from this pointer `cash` like `cash->doSomething(5)` only if `ICash` also has a declaration (virtual or not) for `void doSomething(int)`.

So in a nutshell, to be able to use `doSomething` from within a `ICash`, it has to be declared within `ICash` as well.

Note that when `doSomething` is declared in `ICash` and you redefine the method in `control`(overriding) you would want the declaration in `ICash` to be `virtual`.

Comment: you cannot call doSomething directly from outside, as long as it's defined as private.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the methods are declared in their corresponding header classes, but you have to redefine them in your own class if you want them to do something useful.

doSomething in your control class is *private* method, and as such, *won't be available outside its class at all*. But you redefine one or more methods from ICash and ILock interfaces, you can call doSomething from within these methods, for example: suppose an interface has a method methodXXX:

```
class ISomething {
  public:
    virtual void callMe(int value);
}

class control: public ISomething {
  public:
    control();
    void callMe(int value) {
      return doSomething(value);
    }

  private:
    void doSomething(int value);
}

void control::doSomething(int value) {
  // do something :)
}

// somewhere later:
ISomething* something = new control();
something.callMe(5);//calls control.doSomething(5) internally
```